# how to sum in for loop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show the sum of the values which is coming from two dynamic div but below I mention the static version of the div.
Anyone can help me to solve this tiny jquery puzzle :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  arr = $('#cover div p').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  });

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var res = parseInt(arr[i]);
    var res = res+parseInt(arr[i]);
    $('#resultTotal').html(res);
  }

});
```

```css
.slider
{
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#resultTotal
{
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px 10px ;
  margin: 10px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <div class="slider">
    <p class="content">100</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <p class="content">200</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="resultTotal"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues here. Firstly you should call `get()` when using `map()` to only get the array of values you returned instead of an entire collection of jQuery objects.

Secondly, you're doubling the total as you first set `res` to the value in the array, then you redefine `res` and add the value to it again... for some reason. You're also looping twice for no good reason; once to create the array and again through the array. Just loop once.

Lastly, as you're working with dynamic content you need to perform this sum logic *after* the elements have been added. As such, place it in a function and call it when necessary.

The simplest way to achieve this would be to create a `total` variable which you increment with the text value of the `p` within an `each()` loop, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // after you add the dymamic .slider p elements:
  calculateAndDisplayTotal();
});

function calculateAndDisplayTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('#cover div p').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  });
  
  $('#resultTotal').text(total);
}
```

```css
.slider {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#resultTotal {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <div class="slider">
    <p class="content">100</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <p class="content">200</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="resultTotal"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The OP mentions that these are "two dynamic div" which I assume means that they'll be added to the DOM after it has loaded. Does this code account for this?

Comment: It doesn't. However all that would need to change is to put the logic in to a function and then you call that function after the `.slider p` elements have been added to the DOM. I've edited the question to show a more appropriate example, thanks.

Comment: Actually `get()` not really needed when using OP's `for` loop

Comment: @charlietfl agreed, but the OP is also using `map()`

Comment: Right, but the resultant object does have length. Not a critical issue ...works both ways in OP's case

Answer (score 0):

Working example,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  arr = $('#cover>div>p').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  });
  
var res = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res = res+parseInt(arr[i]);
    $('#resultTotal').html(res);
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <div class="slider">
    <p class="content">100</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <p class="content">200</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="resultTotal"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```